# How To Prevent Apps on macOS from Moving Themselves to the Applications Folder?

Tags: macos, security, skype, virus, join

Some apps, like "Skype Meetings App" and "Join.me" surrepticiously copy themselves to your applications folder without asking or even so much as a notification.

**How can this be prevented?**

Isn't this a fairly large security hole in macOS...  What is to stop a virus from using the same opportunity in the system?

Comment: Where are these apps suddenly & without notification jumping from?

Comment: When I test drive an app from the Downloads folder or from a folder on the desktop "Under Evaluation". Even when the app is in the ~/Applications folder.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can try either of those without some involved sign-up process, so I can't test.

Comment: I think the join.me app can be downloaded from their web site using this link: https://secure.join.me/Download.aspx?code=490406870&ticket=110771191&oneTimeLoginTicket=01_wOqiYlIdF7tTUhJYmdOhAeJHFk2eRUKp1vNDa&isPurlBased=true&uniqueId=b85bddf8-c070-4da4-ab48-d3515775aa6f

Comment: if you launch the app, then quit the app, it should try and copy itself from wherever it is into your /Applications folder. @Tetsujin

Comment: I see what you mean. In theory, by running it you've given it 'permission to run, as admin' which it then considers to also be 'permission to move to Apps' where it 'ought to be'. I'm not a fan of this interpretation either, but I don't see as they're actually breaking any security law or rule, even though it is a bit insidious. I wish you luck, but idk how you would prevent this, short of not touching with a barge-pole.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the app can be prevented from surreptitiously moving itself by setting the "Locked" switch (bit) in the Finder.

Case in point:

[image]

*and now Join.me does not relocate itself without my permission or knowledge.*